# Can you retrieve facebook photos in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Is there anyway to retrieve photos that are not the profile picture on Unity through the facebook api? or any other way?

Comment: See 1) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API and 2) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos

Answer (score 0):

**1. Easiest** 
Use www class to fetch the image texture.

```
   string link = https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/" + friendID + "/picture?width=50&height=50&redirect=true;

    WWW pic = new WWW (link);
    yield return pic;
    if (pic.error == null) 
    {
         go.renderer.material.mainTexture = pic.texture;
    }
```

where friendID is your facebook id. Here you can pass the id for any of your friends.

width and height to specify what dimension do you want the image to be.

**2. A bit complex but useful in long run** 
link to pass to www class
string link = https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/" + friendID + "/picture?width=50&height=50&redirect=false;

the difference in this method is that you are now not redirecting to the cdn permanent link. 
this will give you a json file. Now you can parse the json file to get the actual link.

use this link again with www class to get the actual image

benefits of using this method.
You can save the image once and next time just ping for permanent link only.. if they match then don't fetch image again.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck. Facebook themselves have made a tutorial for Unity, which is a small game using Facebook's profile pictures. [Here is a link to it.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Not sure what platform are you using.
You can use Facebook official SDK from here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity

Authorise your platform, facebook will give you a token.
Then you can call graph API to get whatever you need.
For Example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cphotos&version=v2.2&